# .htaccess disallow access to files by path without extension

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Example.

I have a file `site.com/file.html`

As expected, I can see file under link `site.com/file.html`

But unexpectedly I see it under link `site.com/file` as well. So no extension URI shows, if exists, file with .html extension as far as I can see.

How can I omit this ?

> To be closer to real life my PHP application URL `site.com/file` is overridden by the HTML file placed in the root. Apache doesn't reach my PHP URL, but shows the HTML page. If I remove the HTML file, then PHP-driven url fires. But I must have that .html file there present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I have ended up with `Options -MultiViews` in `.htaccess`

So it seems I have enabled `MultiViews` by default and it works that way I don't need:

> The effect of MultiViews is as follows: if the server receives a request for /some/dir/foo, if /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's requirements.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html

But I don't see or understand any side-effects for now.

If someone has a better answer, please post.